# How can i make the button move up and down on click and keep it visible?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm trying to do something similer to the map that you can see on this site, http://www.insegment.com/

Everything is going well, but i still need to make the button move up and down on click and keep it visible?

Here's the HTML,

```
<div class="clear">        
<div class="slideTogglebox">
  <button id="slideToggle">Show full map</button>   
</div> </div>
```

Script,

```
$("#slideToggle").click(function () {   
$(this).html(($(this).html()=="Show full map"?"Hide map":"Show full map"));
$(this).toggleClass("moveUp");
$('.slideTogglebox').slideToggle(500); 
});
```

Thank's in advance

Comment: your button id has no ""

Comment: Just have a look at their css, it's all about css (`:hover`, `position:absolute` and `bottom`)

Comment: the button completly hide on click!

Comment: also your moveup doesnt start with a `.`

Comment: just have a look here , qute easy http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_slideup_slidedown

Comment: @MohitBhasi `toggleClass` doesn't allow a selector. The missing `.` is perfectly right here

Comment: Thant's, really helpfull, but i'm not that good with js, can we work with one button only and just change the text inside from show to hide?

Comment: Can you describe your problem using your fiddle? I am not sure I understand what you want to achieve.